# QGIS 'go2streetView' plugin: error message (Qubuntu)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, google-maps, google-street-view

I work with Qubuntu. I installed QGIS 3.32.2-Lima.
I have installed the latest version of the go2streetview plugin.
I requested, got and set this Google API key into the plugin window.

When I use the plugin, I get an error message in the plugin window saying "small problem...an error has occurred.
I paste below a screen shot showing QGIS interface as well as the various messages reported in the QGIS logs console.
I replace the value of the google key with XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX :

[image]

**Log from go2streetview web inspector Menu Elements :**
[image]

**Log from go2streetview web inspector Menu Debug :**
[image]

**Log from go2streetview web inspector Menu Console :**
[image]

**Qgis Logs general Menu window :**

```
   Code:
    2023-10-13T08:48:28     INFO    État de l'application
                 variable d'environnement QGIS_PREFIX_PATH : 
                 Préfixe: /usr
                 Chemin des extensions: /usr/lib/qgis/plugins
                 Chemin des paquets de données: /usr/share/qgis
                 Nom du thème actif: default
                 Chemin du thème actif: /usr/share/qgis/resources/themes/default/icons/
                 Chemin du thème par défaut: :/images/themes/default/
                 Chemins de recherche SVG: /usr/share/qgis/svg/
                  /home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/svg/
                 Chemin de la BD utilisateur: /usr/share/qgis/resources/qgis.db
                 Chemin de la BD d'authentification: /home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/qgis-auth.db
```

** Qgis Logs go2streetview Menu :**

```
    Code:
2023-10-13T09:34:04     INFO    file:///home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/go2streetview/res/g2sv.html?lat=14.748027087080024&long=-17.383023740224072&width=444&height=519&heading=0&APIkey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2023-10-13T09:34:04     INFO    file:///home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/go2streetview/res/g2gm.html?lat=14.748027087080024&long=-17.383023740224072&wi[1]dth=444&height=519&zoom=19&heading=0&APIkey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**Qgis Logs python Menu :**

```
Code:
2023-10-13T09:36:38     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/go2streetview/go2streetview.py", line 534, in openInBrowserAction
              self.openInBrowserSV()
              File "/home/geoteca/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/go2streetview/go2streetview.py", line 754, in openInBrowserSV
              pitch = str(-1 * math.floor(float(p['pitch'])))
             KeyError: 'pitch'
```

**Qgis Logs general Menu :**

```
Code:
2023-10-13T09:36:39     WARNING    Erreur Python : Une erreur est survenue lors de l'exécution du code Python : Voir le journal des erreurs Python pour plus de détails
```

Answer (score 0):

The resolution of the problem here :
https://github.com/enricofer/go2streetview/issues/75